# Making sense of class extension and instance properties in Coffee Script

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

I've just gotten into Coffee Script and am having issues figuring out how class extension works. It seems that properties defined as instance properties on a parent class are being implemented as static properties when that class is extended.

I have a class, called Foo, which I want to use as a base class for two sub classes, Bar and Goo. I give Foo an instance property called foobs and a method for adding a foob, like so:

```coffee-script
class Foo
    foobs:[]
    addFoob: (foob) ->
        @foobs.push(foob)
```

And I extend Foo with Bar and Goo, and create new instances, like so:

```coffee-script
class Bar extends Foo
    otherMethod: ->
        alert 'doing other stuff'

class Goo extends Foo
    secondMethod: ->
        alert 'doing second stuff'

barInstance = new Bar()
gooInstance = new Goo()
```

But then when I add a Foob to barInstance, it also gets added to gooInstance!

```coffee-script
barInstance.addFoob('test')

console.log gooInstance.foobs (outputs ["test"])
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong here. I want barInstance and gooInstance to each have their own "foobs" property, but for some reason it seems that even though foobs is an instance property on Foo, it's getting assigned as a class property on Bar and Goo. Any ideas on how to get around this? Or maybe there's different syntax I'm unaware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how you are declaring `foobs` - you really want it to be on the instance, and so it should be declared in a `constructor` function. At the moment it is declared on the `prototype` which is shared by all instances. If we look at what you're `Foo` declaration compiles to, we can see that this is the case:

```
class Foo
  foobs:[]
  addFoob: (foob) ->
    @foobs.push(foob)
```

compiles to:

```
var Foo = (function() {
  function Foo() {}
  Foo.prototype.foobs = [];
  Foo.prototype.addFoob = function(foob) {
    return this.foobs.push(foob);
  };
  return Foo;
})();
```

What you want to do is declare a constructor like this:

```
class Foo
  constructor: (@foobs = [])->     
  addFoob: (foob) ->
    @foobs.push(foob)
```

Which will add a `foobs` array to each instance of `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Accepting this one because of the cool inline syntax for method arguments (@foobs = []) which I always was annoyed about not being able to do in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are placing the array onto the `Foo` prototype, so it will be shared across all instances. Instead you need to create a array for each instance of `Foo` and add it directly.

```
class Foo
  foobs:null, # This isn't needed, but it's good for documentation.
  constructor: ->
    @foobs = []
  addFoob: (foob) ->
    @foobs.push(foob)
```

Looking at it differently, what you have is essentially:

```
sharedFoobs = []

class Foo
  foobs: sharedFoobs
```

which makes it a bit clearer that a new array is never created.

Answer (score 1):

The `foobs` array should be initialized in the constructor, because right now all instances will share the same `foobs` array because you defined it on the `prototype`.

You can safely define primitive values on the `prototype` because these values are immutable, however you should avoid storing objects in the `prototype`, unless you want these to be shared across all instances.

Comment: I would upvote this one also if I could. Thanks for the explanation about objects on prototypes.